# CSS Error in parsing value for color

Tags: css

I don't what the problem is. I have another selector that has that kind of property and value as well but I'm getting error only on this one.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: are you sure that this is that line?

Comment: Post code (as text) that reproduces the problem. Screenshots are not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason is that you have a NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0 after the colon. Replace it by a normal SPACE (or remove it).

NO-BREAK SPACE is not a whitespace character in CSS, so it is not skipped – instead, it will be parsed as the first character of a color value, leading to a syntax error. (That’s what “found ' '” refers to in the error message.)